# How do you configure Apache on Kodingen?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have a Kodingen account, and can create .htaccess files, which are processed - but how can I configure the httpd.conf?

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to Kodingen's support desk.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Their support desk seems to be pretty busy coding right now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey there - on a free account you are not able to set your own httpd.conf (and paid accounts are not there yet) so you only have .htaccess option for now..